# Dropbox dropins conflicts with underscore

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, dropbox-api

I have a web application that uses Underscorejs and the dropins Dropbox API. 
Today, the web application suddenly stopped working because of a js error at load time:

```
undefined is not a function
```

The error is coming from this statement:

```
_.each(...)
 ^
```

after some debugging, I found out that the `_` global variable is no longer set to `underscore` but is actually set to `dropins` the Dropbox API. Now, all parts of my application relying on `_.` is falling apart.

Commenting out the line where `dropins` get loaded resolves the issue, `underscore` now loads fine. However, my application support for dropbox is totally broken.

**QUESTION**

Has anyone seen this error before? 
How can I resolve it without changing too much of my application code?

Comment: This is a known issue we're working on fixing right now.

Comment: @Greg Thank you for your quick feedback. You just made a couple of customers run away from my app :(

Comment: @Greg Do you know when this will be fixed?  It just hit me as well

Comment: The fix is rolling out now.

Comment: This should be fixed now.